# Firebase UI Auth handle Registration action from implicit navigation from SignInScreen (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have a sign in screen from `SignInScreen` widget as shown below.

[image]

However, if a user does not have an account he can register himself by clicking Register on the screen which will lead me to this page:

[image]

In the documentation, it is called internal navigation: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/flutterfire_ui/doc/auth/integrating-your-first-screen.md#disabling-internal-navigation

The problem I have right now is once a user register, the user did not receive any notification that his account is successfully registered nor the app will automatically redirect him to the email verification or even back to the sign in page.

How do I handle a registration action from the SignInScreen widget?

Below is the code I have for the SignInScreen widget:

```
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SignInScreen(
      actions: [
        AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
          if (!state.user!.emailVerified) {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
          } else {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
          }
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting this behavior again. Consistently, after rebuilding. Using firebase_ui_auth ^1.8.0

Comment: Found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056070/flutter-firebase-ui-auth-registerscreen-does-not-trigger-authstatechangeaction

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced similar behavior - actually it was due to bug (AuthStateChangeAction was not triggered after registration) and it was resolved just recently (firebase_ui_auth version 1.1.8 has been just published).

It was also possible to work it around by listening to Firebase auth instance directly but now it is no longer necessary.

Comment: You perfectly provided the correct answer here a few days later: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056070/flutter-firebase-ui-auth-registerscreen-does-not-trigger-authstatechangeaction

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by rebuilding my app instead of using hot reload, not sure why it happens though.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working  --- I voted to close the question as an ephemeral problem as it's unlikely that others in the same situation will find it.