# Flutter firebase_ui_auth RegisterScreen() does not trigger AuthStateChangeAction event

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

AuthStateChangeAction event is never triggered during registration - both in case of using RegisterScreen() and SignInScreen()

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: RegisterScreen(
        providers: [EmailAuthProvider()],
        actions: [
          AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
            print('AuthStateChangeAction()');
          }),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
        onPressed: () async {
          print('FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()');
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Native FirebaseAuth events are fired normally and they could be used but in case of Signing-in the AuthStateChangeAction is fired in desired way.

This might work as work-around:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
    print('FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()');
  });
}
```

Comment: If you've found a bug in FirebaseUI for Flutter, it might be worth it to file a bug on its repo: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues

Comment: Sure, I will :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is separate handler for 'SignedIn' and 'UserCreated' events.
The second is changing auth state but does not fire SignedIn event.
It looks like this works:

```
    actions: [
      AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
        print('AuthStateSignedIn');
      }),
      AuthStateChangeAction<UserCreated>((context, state) {
        print('AuthStateUserCreated');
      }),
    ],
```

Comment: For "Email Signin Link" feature, neither of these worked.


See related https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10489


User created successfully; clicking link opens application in IOS; but "callback" not being fired.


But thanks for the workaround: this works just fine, I open link in iPhone, and it redirects to "welcome" screen in application (instead of "enter your Email" screen):

  ```FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
   if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      Get.offAllNamed(IntroductionScreen.routeName);
    }
  });```

Comment: I think it should be filed as a separate bug.

I just followed this example with my own Database & AppStore settings, and "EmailLinkAuthProvider" feature didn't work: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_ui_auth/example

However, thanks to @Tymoteusz Chmielewski, this workaround works just fine:   ```FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) { if ... /* navigate to correct screen */}```

Comment: I even suspect that I can use EmailLinkAuthProvider on iPhone, open link on Windows Email client, and after that my iPhone application will automatically "redirect" to correct screen; maybe I need to use `handleCodeInApp: false` for this to work.

Comment: even this doesn't work for me, even removing the "UserCreated" doesn't trigger anything at least